Grails 6.1.2 gives "Unmatched argument at index 0" when trying to run commands
In Grails 6.1.2, Creating a new application with the Grails Shiro plugin. The command grails shiro-quick-start through the Grails CLI results in the following error:
[Unmatched argument at index 0: 'shiro-quick-start' 
Did you mean grails create-service or grails create-restapi or grails create-taglib?](https://i.sstatic.net/tOZUU.png)

The CLI commands added by the plugin does not work. There are significant changes in the new Grails CLI, where a bunch of commands similar to the grails run-app are removed, and instead use gradle bootRun to run the application, and the commands added by plugin does not work. However, all the documentation I've been able to find says to use the Grails command.
Here, is how I've added the Grails Shiro plugin in the build.gradle file:
build.gradle
implementation "org.grails.plugins:grails-shiro:4.4"

How to run/add commands added through the Grails Plugin? or How to add a new command in the Grails Plugin?

Have you tried using the same command with ./gradlew from the project root instead of grails?

Yes, I did try that.  I got "build failed with an exception" which is what I expected since the project won't currently compile

In Grails 6, a revamped Command-line Interface (CLI) has been introduced, boasting improved speed and flexibility compared to its predecessor. A notable enhancement is the elimination of redundant tasks such as 'grails run-app'.
However, it's important to note that this CLI operates entirely offline, lacking awareness of the Grails application or its plugins. Consequently, commands from plugins will no longer function as expected.
As an alternative, you can implement a custom application command through the plugin, executable as a Gradle task. For instance, the Grails Spring Security Core Plugin supports the s2-quickstart command, which can be executed as shown below:
./gradlew runCommand -Pargs="s2-quickstart"

In addition to the explanation provided, let's include an example of how to create a custom application command within a Grails plugin:
Suppose we want to create a custom command called 'custom-command' within our plugin. Here's how we can implement it:
grails-app/commands/your/plugin/package/CustomCommand.groovy
package your.plugin.package

import grails.cli.GrailsApplicationCommand
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

class CustomCommand implements GrailsApplicationCommand {

    static final USAGE = "Usage: grails custom-command [options]"

    static final COMMAND_NAME = 'custom-command'

    @Autowired
    YourService yourService // Assuming you have a service you want to use

    @Override
    String getName() {
        COMMAND_NAME
    }

    @Override
    String getDescription() {
        "This is a custom command example."
    }

    @Override
    String getUsage() {
        USAGE
    }

    @Override
    boolean handle() {
        // Add your custom logic here
        yourService.doSomething()
        println "Executing custom command..."
        return true // Return true to indicate successful execution
    }
}

Now, you can run this command as:
./gradlew runCommand -Pargs="custom-command"

Alternatively, you could add the plugin dependency to the buildSrc/build.gradle as:
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:4.3.0")
    implementation("org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:6.2.1-SNAPSHOT")
    implementation("org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:8.1.0")
    implementation("your.plugin.package:myplugin:1.0.0") { transitive = false }
}

This will add a Gradle task named customCommand which can be executed as:
./gradlew customCommand -Pargs="option1 option2 ..."

Hope it helps!

I had to modify the import and change the extends to implements in your CustomCommand.groovy. Tested it with Grails 6.1.2:
import grails.dev.commands.GrailsApplicationCommand
class CustomCommand implements GrailsApplicationCommand {
Questions:

Is there any newer/other implementation of custom commands in Grails 6.2.0? Or where does your Example come from?
Is there an option in the command "not-to-start" the application?
What is the replacement for custom-scripts (https://docs.grails.org/6.0.0/guide/commandLine.html#creatingCustomScripts) in Grails > 6.1.2?


https://medium.com/@puneetbehl/a-comprehensive-guide-to-custom-application-command-in-grails-framework-f7496406ac50
